# Localization unit tests for Symfony 2

Tags: symfony, phpunit, locale

When running `phpunit -c vendor/symfony/` 24 of 10758 assertions fail. The errors exclusively occur in localization tasks... some examples:

```
1) Symfony\Tests\Component\Form\Extension\Core\DataTransforme\DateTimeToLocalizedStringTransformerTest::testTransformLongTime
Failed asserting that two strings are equal.
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
-'03.02.2010 04:05:06 GMT+00:00'
+'03.02.2010 04:05:06 GMT'


12) Symfony\Tests\Component\Locale\Stub\StubNumberFormatterTest::testFormatCurrencyWithCurrencyStyleIntl with data set #3 (100, 'BRL', 'R$100.00')
Failed asserting that two strings are equal.
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
-'R$100.00'
+'BR$100.00'
```

It seems there is something wrong with my php.ini or config.yml settings but i cannot figure out what. I searched stackoverflow, symfony forums and google of course but couldn't find any solution.

I set up everything as listed here (well, except APC): http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/reference/requirements.html
The requirements check doesn't yield any errors.

Any ideas?

---

- OS: MacOS X 10.6.8
- PHP Version: PHP 5.3.8
- Symfony2 Version: 2.0.5/2.0.9
- ICU Version: 4.8.1
- date.timezone in php.ini: "Europe/Berlin"
- locale setting in symfony's parameters.ini: de

Comment: What does the specification says about ini configuration values to run the test-suite? The original author of the suite might have provided a bootstrap file for the suite, an XML configuration file or commandline parameters how to invoke it properly.

Comment: I am using the supplied XML configuration in vendor/symfony. All other requirements (php config-wise) should be met.

Answer (score 0):

This is commonly a symptom of not having a time zone set properly.

Make sure in your php.ini, you have something like

```
date.timezone = 'America/Chicago'
```

Comment: It's set to 'Europe/Berlin' (checked with `php -i | grep 'date.timezone'`)